# groff registers not defined during macro

Tags: man, groff, roff

### Context:

Let's say I am trying to write a macro in groff in order to draw a rectangle given some arguments (like width and height for example).
For this I need to perform some simple arithmetic, that I would like to store in registers for readability.

### How to reproduce

In any normal groff document I can just use:

```
.nr a 1  \"creates a number register with the name a and the value 1
\n[a]      \"prints the content of register a
```

which prints `1` on the document
However when I place it in a macro `MACRO` and call it like so:

```
.de MACRO  \"defines a new macro with name MACRO
.nr a 1    \"creates a number register with the name a and the value 1
\n[a]        \"prints the content of register a
..         \"end of MACRO definition
.MACRO     \"calls MACRO
```

It prints `0`, which is the default value for new registers, according to the documentation (`man groff`, `man 7 groff`, and `info groff`).

### How it is compiled

I compile it using this script:

```
groff -kep "$file" -Tpdf > "$file.pdf"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to use registers inside of a macro? How should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to use registers inside a macro, but you have to tell troff to wait evaluating the value to be evaluated at the time the macro is *called*, instead of *defined*.

You therefore have to escape the backslash in front of the line asking for the register value in the macro definition, ending up with

```
.de MACRO  \"defines a new macro with name MACRO
.nr a 1    \"creates a number register with the name a and the value 1
\\n[a]       \"prints the content of register a
..         \"end of MACRO definition
.MACRO     \"calls MACRO
```

This ways, the value given within the macro is printed, so `1` in this case.